# Sending mail with c# html formatted

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

I know there are a lot of question similar to this one but I cannot seem to find the right answer. 
So in my page I have CKEditorControl I want to use its content and send it as text. The problem is that the email is send with all the tags and they are not rendered put pasted as plain text.

```
  public class MailSender
{
    private readonly MailMessage mailMessage;
    private SmtpClient smtpClient;
    private string fromEmail = myMail;
    private string fromPass = myPass;

    public MailSender()
    {
        this.mailMessage = new MailMessage();

        this.mailMessage.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
        this.mailMessage.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

        this.mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(MyMail);


    }

    public void Send(string subject, string body, params string[] to)
    {
        this.mailMessage.Body = body;           
        this.mailMessage.Subject = subject;
        this.mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        foreach (var mail in to)
        {
            this.mailMessage.To.Add(mail);
        }

        using (this.smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 25))
        {
            this.smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            this.smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            this.smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            this.smtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(this.fromEmail, this.fromPass);
            this.smtpClient.Send(this.mailMessage.From.ToString(), this.mailMessage.To.ToString(), this.mailMessage.Subject, this.mailMessage.Body);
        }

    }
}
```

This is the class which is responsible for sending my emails.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code that I've wrote an worked perfectly for me

Default.aspx

```
<CKEditor:CKEditorControl ID="CKEditor1" BasePath="~/_Samples/ckeditor/" runat="server"></CKEditor:CKEditorControl>
    <asp:Button ID="SaveButton" runat="server" OnClick="SaveButton_Click" Text="Save Me" />
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            Mail.SendMail("email@gmail.com", "cke", CKEditor1.Text);
        }
```

Email.cs

```
public static void SendMail(string To, string Subject, string Body)
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress(SmtpUserName, SmtpFrom);
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(To));
            message.Subject = Subject;
            message.Body = Body;
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
            message.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;

            var client = new SmtpClient(SmtpAddress, SmtpPort)
            {
                Credentials = new NetworkCredential(SmtpUserName, SmtpPassword),
            };

            client.Send(message);            
        }
```

I used lost of rich text editor features, bold, italic, colors ... and received email with bold, italic and colorful text.

Comment: This didn't work. What is happening is that the code from CKEditorControl is with html tags for example <h1>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;HEADER</h1>  And I want to be rendered as a normal header, instead it pasted as the text you see

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I was sending the message body and not the whole message. Thank you for the advice